# Webserver process resistant to Ctrl+Z

Tags: macos, process, webserver

I'm trying out different Python web-microframeworks, such as cherrypy and flask (under Mac OSX).

When I end the process with CTRL+Z usually the processes lives on. Why does the shutdown signal not kill the process? I have to sudo kill it and restart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ctrl-Z, is suspend. You want Ctrl-C, interrupt.
From [Unix signal wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal):

> - Ctrl-C (in older Unixes, DEL) sends an INT signal (SIGINT); by default, this causes the process to terminate.
> - Ctrl-Z sends a TSTP signal (SIGTSTP); by default, this causes the process to suspend execution.

Comment: cool, thx. glad I asked.